# How to reverse a string and replace chars?

Tags: php, html, string

I have been asked by an interviewer for a test:

```
$string = "This is sample string";
// Output: "string_sample_is_This";
```

what does this question mean..?

I assumed that he was asking about a simple `echo`, am I right or would he expected something else from me ?

```
<?php       
    $string = "This is sample string";
    echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He definetly asked for something else ...

```
<?php 

    $string = explode(" ","This is sample string");
    $string = array_reverse($string);
    $string = implode("_",$string);
    echo $string;

?>
```

More :

[PHP explode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php)

[PHP array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-reverse.php)

[PHP implode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php)

Comment: i could do this but in diff approach but unfortunately i did not understand the question at that time.!

Comment: You may be stressed at this moment, but don't worry, continue to work hard on it and one day, you ll be an expert ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like you are being asked to reverse the order of the tokens in the string and replace the delimiter from single spaces to the _ character. I would assume that or something similar to such was being asked.

Answer (score 2):

No he told to reverse the sentence and echo the string.

```
<?php
    $string = "This is sample string";
    $string1 = '';
    $string_array = explode(' ',$string);
    $count = count($string_array) - 1;
    for($i=$count; $i>=0; $i--)
    {
    if($i == 0)
    {
    $string1 .= $string_array[$i];
    }
    else
    {
    $string1 .= $string_array[$i]."_";
    }
    }
    echo $string1;
?>
```

Comment: @pirs okay. Thanks for your comment. but this is another way to achieve the output.